# Custom enum item

Tags: kotlin, enums

As I know in Swift we can create custom item in enum like this

```
enum MyEnum {
  case item1
  case item2
  case custom(param1: String)

  var param1: String {
    switch self {
    case .item1:
      return "Item 1"
    case .item2:
      return "Item 2"
    case let .custom(param1):
      return param1
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible in Kotlin? If yes, how to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible with `Enum`s in Kotlin, but you can do something similar with Sealed classes:

```
sealed class MySealedClass(val param1: String) {
    object Type1 : MySealedClass("Type 1")
    object Type2 : MySealedClass("Type 2")
    class Custom(param1: String) : MySealedClass(param1)
}
```

See [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) for reference.